# Find array elements that have a certain key-name prefix

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array with lots of elements and want to get a list of all elements that have a key name with a certain prefix.

Example:

```
$arr = array(
  'store:key' => 1,
  'user' => 'demo',
  'store:foo' => 'bar',
  'login' => true,
);

// this is where I need help with:
// the function should return only elements with a key that starts with "store:"
$res = list_values_by_key( $arr, 'store:' );

// Desired output:
$res = array(
  'store:key' => 1,
  'store:foo' => 'bar',
);
```

Comment: Have you tried something or did some research?

Comment: I tried to solve it with `array_intersect_keys( $arr, array('store:') )` but this function obviously requires exact keys and cannot handle filters like `store:*`

Comment: ^ See your on the right path! Just edit your question and add you attempt and show where you are stuck and can't get any further.

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do :

```
$arr = array(
  'store:key' => 1,
  'user' => 'demo',
  'store:foo' => 'bar',
  'login' => true,
);

$arr2 = array();
foreach ($arr as $array => $value) {
    if (strpos($array, 'store:') === 0) {
        $arr2[$array] = $value;
    }
}
var_dump($arr2);
```

Returns :

```
array (size=2)
'store:key' => int 1
'store:foo' => string 'bar' (length=3)
```

Comment: Using a loop, why did I not think about this before? :-) I think this is the easiest and most simple way to solve the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

Just grab all keys which starts with `store:` with [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) from your array. And then do a simple [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) call to get the intersect of both arrays.

```
<?php

    $arr = array(
      'store:key' => 1,
      'user' => 'demo',
      'store:foo' => 'bar',
      'login' => true,
    );

    $result = array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip(preg_grep("/^store:/", array_keys($arr))));
    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [store:key] => 1
    [store:foo] => bar
)
```

Comment: Solution is true  but I'd be afraid to use a flip

Comment: @splash58 Why? I'm dealing with keys, so they have to be unique

Comment: This was what I originally intended to do. Seeing this now I get the impression that using four different array functions make this solution a bit complex... and possibly also slower than a simple loop.

Answer (score 0):

From php 5.6 you can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$return = array_filter($array, function ($e) {
        return strpos($e, 'store:') === 0;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

var_dump($return);
```

for earlier versions, you can use

```
$return = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip(array_filter(array_keys($array), function ($e) {
    return strpos($e, 'store:') === 0;
})));
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/UFtUU).